# The {typesetting} tag.

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

What purpose does the [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) tag serve?

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting):

> Typesetting is the retrieval of the
>   stored letters (called sorts in
>   mechanical systems and glyphs in
>   digital systems) and the ordering of
>   them according to a language's
>   orthography for visual display.

Hence it is what TeX does internally, though I think the process of writing a TeX file is usually also called typesetting. Reading through the list of questions tagged [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) I see several questions that should be tagged [typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography), some where [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) is entirely superfluous and some where it is applied as a catch-all tag.

Should [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) be removed?

Comment: I agree. Some could be merged into {typography}, some others require a different tag, especially those with {typesetting} as the only tag.

Comment: This seems to be accepted. Let me take a couple of days to go through the {typesetting} questions, then a mod can do the merging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) and retagged anything that is not about typography. Could a mod please merge [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) into [typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) and delete [typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typesetting) afterwards (in order to avoid future confusion).

Comment: I merged {typesetting} into {typography}. I kept {typesetting} as an alias. It's not very visible, since it redirects to {typography}. This way recreation of {typesetting} is prevented.

Comment: I tagged this thread as {status-completed} as requested. Thanks for the retagging!